# Extremely strong peak around 10 eV energy of Aluminum crystal in an x-ray inelastic scattering experiment

Tags: spectroscopy, metals, x-rays, fermi-energy, plasmon

I conducted an experiment where I measured Bragg reflection for two different atomic planes (200 and 400) of Aluminum crystal at an energy of 10 KeV. Then, in each of these two measurements I shifted the input x-ray beam by some small deviation from the Bragg angle (after I found Bragg), say about 0.2 degrees (where the width of the Bragg peak was about 0.15 degrees) and measured the energy of the output beam in a range of 9960 to 9995 eV. In both of the reflections I had a strong pronounced peak at around 10 eV. Any idea what could cause this? This energy is very close to the surface plasmon energy and also to the Fermi energy of Aluminum. (There was no significant peak at the bulk plasma energy, 15.8 eV). Also, this peak didn't originate from the experimental setup (I checked it with another sample...).

Thanks!

Comment: Your description is unclear. How do you measure the energy of the output beam? If you are measuring the energy in the range  9960 to 9995 eV, how are you seeing a peak at 10 eV? When asking a question about a peak in a spectrum, it is best to actually show the spectrum with clearly specified axes. What was the "other sample"?  How are the X-rays produced? …